# div showing up in front of @body in Blazor

Tags: html, css, blazor

The grid is showing up in front of my @Body, which is supposed to be in front. I mainly had little idea to what I was doing, however I used div's and backgrounds to the best of my knowledge. Is there any reason why one takes priority over the other, since @Body should be in the front.

```
<!-- MainLayout.razor -->
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page" id="hero">
    <div id="landscape-grid"></div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="px-4">
            Best Hackathon Project
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .page {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    main {
        flex: 1;
    }

    html, body {
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #hero {
        background-image: linear-gradient(#d80368 -12%, #f75c03 100%);
        height: 100vh; /* Set the height of the hero section to full viewport height */
        overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow to prevent scrolling */
        position: relative; /* Set position to relative for absolute positioning of landscape-grid */
    }

    #landscape-grid {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d80368 1.5px, transparent 1.5px), linear-gradient(to right, #d80368 1.5px, transparent 1.5px);
        background-size: 5vh 5vh, 80px 80px;
        background-position: 0 0, 0 0;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        animation: moveUp 15s linear infinite forwards;
    }

    @keyframes moveUp {
        0% {
            background-position: 0 0, 0 0;
        }

        100% {
            background-position: 0 -100vh, 0 -100vh;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is clearly html/css issue. Please share the code on codepen.io or similar so we can hop in and try to fix it. You can obtain the generated html from developer tools (F12) in your browser